# Find all $b$ such that $(t,t+b)$ is tangent to circle.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

This is problem 3 on page 147 of ideals varieties and algorithms. We use the following definition of tangent line:

[image]

where multiplicity is defined as

[image]

**Statement of problem**: Consider the straight lines \begin{align*} x&=t \\ y&=b+t \end{align*} These lines have slope $1$ and $y$-intercept $b$. For which values of $b$ is the line tangent to the circle $x^2+y^2=2$?

My answer: None.

Proof:

Let $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2-2$. In order to determine the values of $b$ for which the line is tangent to the circle I substitute into $f(x,y)$ the parameterizations for the coordinates $x$ and $y$ of the points of the line and get a new function in $t$:

\begin{align*} g(t)=f(t,b+t) = 2t^2+2tb+b^2-2 \end{align*}

The roots of $g(t)$ are the values of $t$ for which the line $(t,t+b)$ and the circle intersect. For $b \neq \pm \sqrt{2}$, $g(t)$ has no roots.

Assume $b=\sqrt{2}$. Then $g(t)$ has two roots $t_1=0$ and $t_2=-\sqrt{2}$. Now I still need to show that the line is tangent to the circle at some point for this value of $b$. Now the line intersects the circle at the point $(-\sqrt{2},0)$ with multiplicity $1$, and since the definition of tangent line requires this multiplicity to be $\ge 2$, it is clear that the line is not tangent to the circle at $(-\sqrt{2},0)$ without further inspection. Similarly, the line  intersects the circle at the point $(0, \sqrt{2})$ with multiplicity $1$, and so the line is not tangent to the circle at this point by the same reasoning.

The same logic holds in showing $b=-\sqrt{2}$ results in points of intersection at which the line meets the circle with multiplicity less than $2$ and, therefore, the line is not tangent to the circle at these points, either.

Therefore, no such value of $b$ exists.

I'm very unsure about this. Is my answer and proof correct or incorrect? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

i think $b = \pm2,$ for the line $y = x \pm 2$ is tangent to $x^2 + y^2 = 2$ at $(\mp 1, \pm 1).$

Comment: and similarly, $b=-2$.

Comment: @DanUznanski, thanks for the clarification.